# xPages OSGi Extension Library for Relational Driver

Tags: osgi, xpages, xpages-extlib

I have been looking at using the relational data access in the xpages extension library. I have it working, but I put the jar on the server to get it to work. The recommended method of deploying the jdbc driver seems to be through a custom extension library.

Does there exist some instructions on how to create this. I don't have any experience in creating OSGi plugins at all so I am a bit out of my element here.

Comment: FYI: http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPages%20JDBC%20Driver%20Wrapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patrick,
it is easier than it looks like. In Eclipse (or the Java view of Domino Designer) you create a plug-in project. There you define the Extension point that makes it an extension library and implement a simple class (mainly returning the version).

Your plug-in.xml would look like this (you might have other content too):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <!-- This makes the plug-in an XPages extension library -->
   <extension point="com.ibm.commons.Extension">
      <service class="com.ibm.ctp.CoreLibrary" type="com.ibm.xsp.Library">
      </service>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

In the manifest (Eclipse has a nice editor, so don't worry) you make sure to export the JDBC driver packages, so they become visible. Finally your activator class looks like this:

```
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

public class Activator extends Plugin {

// The shared instance
private static Activator    plugin;
private static String       version;

/**
 * Returns the shared instance
 * 
 * @return the shared instance
 */
public static CSIActivator getDefault() {
    return plugin;
}

public static String getVersion() {
    if (version == null) {
        try {
            version = plugin.getBundle().getHeaders().get("Bundle-Version").toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            version = "3.7.2";
        }
    }
    return version;
}

public Activator() {
    // No Action needed
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin#start(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext)
 */
@Override
public void start(final BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    super.start(context);
    plugin = this;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin#stop(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext)
 */
@Override
public void stop(final BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    plugin = null;
    super.stop(context);
}

}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: It does help. I will need to play around with it for a bit first though. Do you have an opinion on the jdbc driver wrapper project on openNTF?

Comment: Andrejus for sure knows his stuff, so use the project http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPages%20JDBC%20Driver%20Wrapper . Feel free to accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

There are also detailed instructions in the book, [XPages Extension Library](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/Redbooks.nsf/ibmpressisbn/9780132901819), starting from page 381. The author uses DB2 in the example, but it was quite easy to switch to MySQL driver.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new OpenNTF project that you can use to create a plug-in for a JDBC driver.  See http://www.openntf.org/Internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPages%20JDBC%20Driver%20Wrapper

Howard

Comment: Have you used this plugin?